onChange doesn't work on Custom Input inside Controller Wrapper
I'm working on a React project with TypeScript, using react-hook-form and the form components from shadcn/ui (shadcn/ui form example).
I've created a custom Input component with a button (containing a pen icon) that toggles the readonly property of the input.
Desired Functionality
When the user clicks the pen button, the input becomes editable.
As soon as the input value changes, replace the pen button with a submit button.
The input should return to readonly state only after the submit button is clicked and the form is submitted.
This behavior should apply to every input in the form.
Problem
The onChange property doesn't seem to work for detecting value changes or setting a state to swap the buttons.
Attempting to use react-hook-form hooks like useFormContext to get the control prop, and then using useWatch or useFormState, results in excessive re-renders.
I'm looking for suggestions on how to implement this functionality efficiently. If you have ideas on how to modify my current component to achieve this, I'd greatly appreciate your help.
Implementation on Stackblitz
StackBlitz - Playground

I see no use of react-hook-form in the code you have provided.

The component itself is wrapped inside a react-hook-form Controller just made with shadcn/UI. I didn't put the solutions I wrote to not make people improve something that may be wrong to begin with.

the useFormState hook allows you to monitor whether the form is dirty, and even more granularly whether a particular field is dirty.  It sounds to me like you'd click the pen button to unlock the field, then once the field is dirty you'd swap the pen button for the submit button.  Once you submit and reset the form the field would no longer be dirty and the submit button would swap back to the pen button .

The last bit is exactly what I want to do, I used the useFormContext to get the control object and then I pass it to the useFormState, like this: const { control } = useFormContext(); const { isDirty } = useFormState({ control, name: props.name});
Now if it's dirty I need to get the changed value, so I used the hook useWatch and I gave it the same params as useFormState:
const result = useWatch({ control, name: props.name as string}).
But when I console log the isDirty and result value, it renders all the fields using the component and a lot of times.

One thing to note, if you are inside of a form context you don't need to pass control to useFormState.  It will automatically find it from context.   You also don't need to watch the value.  All you need to do is get the value on submit.  all the methods of useForm are available on form context so in your submit method you just call methods.getValues.  If you're going to do all that, you only need the use context hook because it also has formState available.

There's a problem, when I use the getValues from the useFormContext, since I can't use the useForm hook again inside the component so the only way is to get it through useFormContext, but when I do this: getValues(props.name), I don't get the value of the input being used or changed but all the values of the fields using the EditableInput component, same with isDirty or any other return value.

What version of react hook form are you using?

here it is from the package.json: "react-hook-form": "^7.50.1"

Since you have access to formContext you should be able to do something like this.
const EditableInput = React.forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, EditableInputProps>(
({ className, editPermission = true, ...props }, ref) => {

    const {formState, getValues, resetField} = useFormContext(); // returns all the same methods and properties that useForm does. 

    const [canEdit, setCanEdit] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
    const disabled = props.disabled || !editPermission;

    const handleEdit = () => {

        const value = getValue(props.name)
         ....do something with the value....
        if (!disabled) {
            setCanEdit((prev) => !prev);
        }
       ...finally...
       resetField(props.name, {defaultValue:value})  // this should reset the dirty state and the default value for the field so dirty can be properly detected. 
       
    };

    const isDirty = formState.dirtyFields[props.name]  // this should be stateful and usable in your JSX to trigger conditional rendering. 

    return (
        <div className="relative">......



That will allow you to listen to the specific fields dirty state, get the value of the field on demand and then reset the field and it's default value which should also trigger the field to no longer be dirty.
Note on using the old render props and Controller api
Value and isDirty might be available directly on props, it might be worth investigating.
Small example with a typical form Implementation
Here is a link to a playground showing how this would work with a typical implementation of react-hook-form Stackblitz - Playground
Editable Input component


import {
  ChangeEventHandler,
  forwardRef,
  useEffect,
  useRef,
  useState,
} from 'react';
import { Controller, useFormContext } from 'react-hook-form';

type Props = {
  name: string;
};

type InputProps = {
  name: string;
  onChange: (val: string) => void;
  value: string;
};

const Input = forwardRef<HTMLInputElement, InputProps>(function Input(
  { value, ...props }: InputProps,
  ref
) {
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement | null>(null);
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
  const {
    formState: { dirtyFields },
    resetField,
    getValues,
  } = useFormContext();
  const isDirty = !!dirtyFields[props.name];
  const handleChange: ChangeEventHandler<HTMLInputElement> = (e) => {
    const val = e.target.value;
    props.onChange?.(val);
  };

  const handleUpdate = () => {
    const value = getValues(props.name);
    resetField(props.name, { defaultValue: value });
    setIsEditing(false);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isEditing) {
      inputRef.current?.focus();
    }
  }, [isEditing]);
  return (
    <div className="input-wrapper">
      <input
        ref={(e) => {
          if (e) {
            inputRef.current = e;
          }
          if (typeof ref === 'function') {
            ref(e);
          }
        }}
        type="text"
        value={value}
        name={props.name}
        onChange={handleChange}
        disabled={!isEditing}
        className={isEditing ? 'active' : ''}
      />
      {isDirty ? (
        <button type="button" onClick={handleUpdate}>
          Update
        </button>
      ) : (
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => {
            setIsEditing((p) => !p);
          }}
        >
          Edit
        </button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
});

export default function EditableInput(props: Props) {
  return (
    <Controller
      name={props.name}
      render={(props) => {
        return (
          <Input
            value={props.field.value}
            name={props.field.name}
            onChange={props.field.onChange}
            ref={props.field.ref}
          />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
}



form component


import { useState } from 'react';
import EditableInput from './enditable-input';
import { useForm, FormProvider, SubmitHandler } from 'react-hook-form';

const defaultValues = {
  field1: '',
  field2: '',
  field3: '',
  field4: '',
};

export default function Form() {
  const [result, setResult] = useState<typeof defaultValues | null>(null);
  const methods = useForm({ defaultValues });
  const handleSubmit: SubmitHandler<typeof defaultValues> = (data) => {
    setResult(data);
  };
  const handleReset = () => {
    setResult(null);
    methods.reset(defaultValues);
  };
  return (
    <div className="form-container">
      <FormProvider {...methods}>
        <form
          className="form"
          id="form-test"
          onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(handleSubmit)}
        >
          <EditableInput name="field1" />
          <EditableInput name="field2" />
          <EditableInput name="field3" />
          <EditableInput name="field4" />
        </form>
        <div className="control-container">
          <button type="submit" form="form-test" className="button">
            Submit
          </button>
          <button
            type="button"
            className="button"
            onClick={() => handleReset()}
          >
            reset
          </button>
        </div>
      </FormProvider>
      {result && <pre>{JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)}</pre>}
    </div>
  );
}




the value variable always returns undefined, even when provided the props.name.

Passing the name should just narrow the returned value to the one property we care about. Calling getValues with no arguments should return the entire state of the form. If it's not then there is something unique about your form implementatiom that I am missing.  Verifying that your overall form submit is getting values, correct?

Even if I pass the name to the getValues I get undefined, One thing I noticed is that if I use onChange on the Input It doesn't work: <Input onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.value) // returns nothing} />, but it works when I give it to the EditableInput like this: <EditableInput {...field} onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.value) // returns the changed value} />
I feel like the onChange is the only way to solve my problem, but I don't know why?

There is something about your implementation that I am missing.  I will work up a small playground with basic components showing how this would work. Integrating that flow into your implementation might be another story.

Here is a mini replica of my project with just two fields, I explained everything inside the component editable-input.tsx: Stackblitz - Playground.
Thanks for taking out of your time to help me.

I have edited your playground to effect the suggestions I have made in my answer above.  The main file I edited was the EditableInput component, though I did make some "quality of life" changes to a couple of naming conventions in the Form and App components.  https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-jgtypv?file=src%2FApp.tsx,src%2Fcomponents%2Fui%2Fform.tsx,src%2Fcomponents%2Feditable-input.tsx.

Thank you very much for your time, I really appreciate it, everything works just like I wanted, one thing I'm struggling with now is the submission of the form when clicking on the submit button inside the input.
Here's what I did:
I renamed the function handleSubmit to submitForm, then I extracted the handleSubmit from the form context like this: const { formState, resetField, getValues, handleSubmit, trigger } = useFormContext();, and inside the submitForm I added the following: handleSubmit((data) => console.log(data));. But it didn't work,
Again, thank you for your help.

You want to submit the entire form after you edit the one field?

It would be really nice if I could just submit that one field but I don't know how using react-hook-form, all I know is that method with handleSubmit, I don't mind either way. Please enlighten me and thank you once again.

Here is a modification to the playground to submit the form after editing the one field. https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-jgtypv?file=src%2FApp.tsx,src%2Fcomponents%2Fui%2Fform.tsx,src%2Fcomponents%2Feditable-input.tsx  You are asking to patch a single value on submit.  That is also possible but you might need to move the submit logic into each component.  Or perhaps you could read the isDirty fields and map your submit to filter out all fields that are not dirty.

I think I have a rough idea of what you mean, I'll figure things out now that at least the submission i working.
You won't believe if I said I still have to add a modal when clicking the submit button to confirm the submission, and thanks to you, I only have a little bit left (hopefully if I don't stuck somewhere).
Thank you once again for your help and effort Scott .

Could you please accept my answer?
